# How do I access data inside objects using ejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm sending data over to my ejs files from my app.js file, and it looks like this:

`{ _id: 2500, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', comments: [ { _id: 5555, title: "Hello", comment: "Hello, World" } ], __v: 0 }`

When using a forEach loop, I can print out the entire document using `<%= document %>`.

I can print out the first and last name using `<%= document.firstName %>`.

When I use `<%= document.comments %>` it prints out the object, but I want it to print out only the "comment" string.  I tried using `<%= document.comments.comment %>`, but nothing gets printed.

How do I access specific data in embedded objects?

Comment: Same way you access it normally; it's just JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments is an array you should
try using `<%= document.comments[0].comment %>` for individual comment in comments array, 
`<%= document.comments[0]%>` for comments array